# Can't Import Unity Package it's greyed out

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, package

Hi I'm following [this official Unity tutorial](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/tutorials/create-with-code-challenge-2-play-fetch-146044?_ga=2.19936120.1512758720.1617295237-120390865.1616904409) and I am trying to open the package in Unity. I've done it before but now the .unitypackage file is greyed out so I can't upon in through the Unity Hub or if I go the the scenes file or if I create new project and try to import it that way. Simply nothing happens.

I'm on the right versions of unity and have tried different versions to. See screenshot. I've tried all Unity installs.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbIST.png)

Comment: That doesnt show you trying to load the package. It shows the hub

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out. I had to open a project and import the package. I tried to open a package without a project already open.